# Why is the isnumber() function present in certain distros of Unix but not in others?

Tags: c, linux, macos, unix, compiler-construction

I'm writing a small C program in which I call the `isnumber()` function.

```
#include <ctype.h>

char c
if(isnumber(c)) 
    { foo }
```

This compiles without a problem on my Mac (OS X 10.8). However, when I upload it to a CentOS 6.x server, it won't compile. Furthermore, [the OS X `man` page for `isdigit()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/isdigit.3.html) describes `isnumber()`, but the CentOS `man` page does not. It's as if it simply doesn't exist on the Linux box. Both [the OS X `man` page for `isdigit()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/isdigit.3.html) and [a general Unix `man` page](http://www.unix.com/man-page/all/3/isnumber/) for `isdigit()` have `isnumber()` listed as part of the C standard library `libc, -lc`. When I add `-lc` to the compile flags on Linux, it still won't compile.

Why is this function included in certain forms on Unix and not in others?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`isnumber()` is a *BSDism*, as can be seen in the HISTORY section of the linked man page:

> The isnumber() function appeared in 4.4BSD.

And there OS X shows its heritage...

Also there is a STANDARDS section that talks about `isdigit` but mutes about `isnumber`.

Anyway, Linux, BSD or OS X man pages should not be considered authoritative about the C language, or even about the POSIX standard. For C read the C standard specification (easy to find around), and for POSIX you can read the [OpenGroup web site](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/).